# HP UFT API Test - Saving Response/Checkpoint values

Tags: hp-uft

Is there a way to capture and store (or write to a file) the values returned in the Response? (Checkpoint values)

Using HP UFT 11.52

Thanks,

Lynn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. In UFT API under Standard Activities, there are File function modules including "Write to File". I added the module to the test, set the path and other properties, passed the variable to the file and it worked! Couldn't be easier.

Comment: Please mark this question as answered so that it closes the question.

Answer (score 1):

I mentioned this on my other answer , you can also write it programatically if you have dynamic array response please refer below:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28012383/3972994

Answer (score 0):

After running a test, in the test folder, you can find a Snapshots/LastIteration directory.
In it you can find the return value for each step saved in a txt file.
Pay attention that if you data drive the step, only the last iteration will be saved to file.
However, in the Test's log (Test dir/Log/vtd_user.log) you can find all the iterations persisted

Thanks,
Yossi

Comment: Thanks Yossi. It's all data driven and I currently get the returned data from the Output pane. What I want is to capture the Response data values and save them either to a spreadsheet or a text file. It would be easier to pass those values to another test but we've chosen not to do it the easy way. ; )

Comment: I figured it out. In UFT API under Standard Activities, there are File function modules including "Write to File". I added the module to the test, set the path and other properties, passed the variable to the file and it worked! Couldn't be easier.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use the standard activities if you do this

```
var iResponse = this.Activity.responsebody;
System.IO.File.WriteLines(@"directorypath&FileName);
```

the above will write the response to the file and rewrite it for every run