# UFT-API: How to write the output of a select data action to the test's data source

Tags: hp-uft

In a uft-api test I have a select data component that returns the query results. The results comeback in an array and I'm trying to figure out how to write the results back to the test's data pane, either excel or local table.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use GetDataSource Class of UFT API , 
it will work like this lets say you imported excel from FlightSampleData.xls, and named it as FlightSampleData, you have `<input>` sheet, accessing the sheet will be like below:

```
GetDataSource("FlightSampleData!input).Set(ROW,ColumnName,yourValue);
GetDataSource("FlightSampleData!input).Get(ROW,ColumnName);
```

I recommend you go to help section of UFT , there are many valuable documents that we thought we never had. all the object reference is out there .

Comment: It's not online , It's UFT Built in help under Help menu

Answer (score 0):

this.Dbfetch10.OutputProperties.GetElementsByTagName("EMP_NAME").item(0).InnerText;

Note :-

EMP_NAME - exact field name in database
Dbfetch10- appropriate stepname of the SelectData

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [answer]. Then, [edit] your question to format a [mcve]  properly.